# Is there a scheme with built-in support for parallel processing?

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, scheme, multicore

I'm looking for a fast, cross-platform scheme dialect with a good FFI and  support for OS-level parallel processing as opposed to "green threads" only. Some high-level concepts like work-stealing approaches, transactional memory, or actors would be great, but a simple interface to OS-level threads would also suffice. R7RS-small support would also be nice.

Is there such an implementation?

*Note: There are several similar questions (on SRFI-18, multicore), but they are quite old, so perhaps something has changed. So far, I've looked at: Guile - not enough cross-platform, Schemik - no longer maintained?, Chicken - would be my favorite, but still only has green threads, Racket - futures are very limited and places seem like a hack.*

Comment: Chez Scheme, which has recently been open-sourced, has threads and parallelism. Gambit Scheme has a Termite library that provides threads and parallelism. I don't know if either does what you want. Neither has R7RS-small; Chez is R6RS and Gambit is R4RS plus lots of more recent stuff.

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful information. I might go for Chez, didn't know it was open sourced, although I'd prefer R7RS over R6RS. (Ironically, I voted for R6RS with the justification that it's not perfect but a standard with module system was desparately needed -- and later somewhat regretted it.)

Comment: @Eric'3ToedSloth' I am working on R7RS for Chez Scheme at https://git.sr.ht/~amz3/chez-scheme-arew

Comment: Well, I consider Guile as very cross-platform (at least among unices)